# Highstock navigator not adjustable

Tags: highcharts

I have a Highstock chart with a few series and a couple of data points per series over several months. I would expect to be able to adjust the selection in the navigator window, but I can't.

```
var seriesOptions = [
    {
    name: 'Apples',
    data: [
        {x: 1525737600000, y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30)},
        {x: 1535737600000, y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30)},
        {x: 1545737600000, y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30)}
    ]
  },
    {
    name: 'Oranges',
    data: [
        {x: 1525737600000, y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30)},
        {x: 1535737600000, y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30)},
        {x: 1545737600000, y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30)}
    ]
  },
    {
    name: 'Grapes',
    data: [
        {x: 1525737600000, y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30)},
        {x: 1535737600000, y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30)},
        {x: 1545737600000, y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30)}
    ]
  }
];

function createChart() {

    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                showInNavigator: true
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>',
            valueDecimals: 0
        },

        series: seriesOptions
    });
}

createChart();
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sallaire4/1u87wh4u/).

Comment: You can also use `xAxis.min` property to change the initial default range: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s5q1gg24/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's cause you don't have enough data :

```
{
  name: 'Oranges',
  data: [
    {x: 1525737600000, y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30)},
    {x: 1528737600000, y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30)},
    {x: 1530737600000, y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30)},
    {x: 1533737600000, y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30)},
    {x: 1535737600000, y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30)},
    {x: 1538737600000, y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30)},
    {x: 1540737600000, y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30)},
    {x: 1540737600000, y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30)},
    {x: 1545737600000, y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30)}
  ]
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ttuoq1sw/)

Comment: That does seem to work.  It looks like I need data points for at least 7 different days in order to be able to adjust the selection.